# Java split using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
"\"value,\",0,6"
```

What should be the regular expression I should use for the split in order to end up with:

```
\"value,\"
0
6
```

So basically I want to ignore the comma in between the escaped double quotes.

Comment: There is no general regular expression for this. You should use a CSV library instead.

Comment: @OlafDietsche And why not just matching instead of splitting ? [See demo](http://regex101.com/r/xO6zZ7). Unfortunately, I'm out of votes otherwise I would have close it as `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.`

Comment: @HamZa You're right, this would be doable. I didn't look for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a CSV parser for some reason, then you could try using a matcher in a loop instead of using split:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]*)(,|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("\"value,\",0,6");
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Breaking this pattern down: `(` (start of group 1) `\"[^\"]*\"` (quote followed by a bunch of non-quote characters followed by a quote) `|` (or) `[^,]*` (bunch of non-comma characters) `)` (end of group 1) `(,|$)` (followed by a comma or end of string)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
String str = "8,2,5,\"bache\\\",tache\",vache,\"value,value\",0,6";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)\"(?>[^\"\\\\]++|\\\\{2}|\\\\.)*+\"|[^,]++");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) { 
    String match = m.group();
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no general regular expression for this. You should use a CSV library instead.

If your string is always of this exact form, you can capture the parts with

```
(".+?"),(\d+),(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your line of text is a fully compliant CSV file, regex is **NOT** the way to go at all. You should use a [CSV parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410538/which-is-the-best-csv-parser-in-java).

That said, given your limited condition, you could use this to split: `,(?!\")`